# multiple definition of (Function)

Tags: c++

I have 3 .cpp files with different main functions:
So I have this error: multiple definition of "enstart()" (The other file has the same code in it but the main function is called "hunstart()"

So, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int enstart()
{
    system("TITLE HUN Homeless Millionaire");
    system("COLOR 0A");
start:
//VARLIB START
    string prominput;
    string workinput;
    string job = "Car Washer";
    string bck;
    string input1;
    string ver = "0.0.1";
    string note = "The game is in a really early state, please ignore the          bugs!";
    string shopinput;
    string admininput;
    int money = 0;
    int snk = 0;
    int shirt = 0;
    int jobmoney = 1;
//VARLIB END
    cout << "Hello, Welcome to Homeless Millionaire!" << endl;
    cout << "Game version: " <<ver << endl;
    cout << "Note: " <<note << endl;
    cout << "Your money: " <<money << endl;
    cout << "Type in a command from below!" << endl;
    cout << "Commands:" << endl;
    cout << "Change-log" << endl;
    cout << "Story" << endl;
    cout << "Creator" << endl;
    cout << "Work" << endl;
    cout << "Shop" << endl;
    input1 = "null";
    cin >> input1;
    if (input1 == "Story") // remove from here
    {
        goto Story;
    }
    else
    {
        if (input1 == "Creator")
        {
            goto Creator;
        }
        else
        {
            if (input1 == "Shop")
            {
                goto shop;
            }
            else
            {
                if (input1 == "Work")
                {
                    goto work;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (input1 == "Change-log")
                    {
                        goto chlog;
                        cout << string( 20, '/n' );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (input1 == "adminpanel")
                            goto admin;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    goto start;
Story:
    system("CLS");

    cout << "The game is about a 18 year old men who went debt." << endl;
    cout << "What did you except?" << endl;
    cout << "Type in back to continue" << endl;
    cout << string( 21, '\n' );
    bck = "null";
    cin >> bck;
    if (bck == "back")
    {
        goto start;
    }
    goto Story;
Creator:
    system("CLS");
    cout << "The game was made by: Killer Doge (C) Karsza Levente" << endl;
    cout << "Co-Creator and Translator: TOMI8401 (C) Deli Bence" << endl;
    cout << "Type in back to continue" << endl;
    bck = "null";
    cin >> bck;
    if (bck == "back")
    {
        goto start;
    }
    goto start;
shop:
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Welcome to the shop!" << endl;
    cout << "Your bank account: " <<money << endl;
    cout << "How to buy: Write in the codes of the selected item!" << endl;
    cout << "     ITEM     |   PRICE   |   CODE   " << endl;
    cout << "    Uniform   |   10 $    |   UNIF   " << endl;
    cout << "   Sneakers   |   25 $    |   SNEK   " << endl;
    cout << "   Trainers   |   35 $    |   TRAN   " << endl;
    cout << "Better Uniform|   50 $    |   BUNI   " << endl;
    cout << "    Shirt     |   50 $    |   SHRT   " << endl;
    cout << " Elegant Shoes|   65 $    |   ESHO   " << endl;
    cout << "  Cheap Phone |   85 $    |   PHON   " << endl;
    shopinput = "null";
    cin >> shopinput;
    if (shopinput == "SNK")
    {
        money -= 25;
        snk = 1;
        goto succb;
    }
    else
    {
        if (shopinput == "SHRT")
        {
            money -= 50;
            shirt = 1;
            goto succb;
        }
    }
    goto shop;
work:
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Your current job: " <<job << endl;
    cout << "Your salary is: " <<jobmoney << endl;
    cout << "Your money is: " <<money << endl;
    cout << "Commands:" << endl;
    cout << "Promote(BUGGY)" << endl;
    cout << "Work" << endl;
    cout << "Back" << endl;
    cout << string( 18, '\n' );
    workinput = "null";
    cin >> workinput;
    if (workinput == "Promote")
    {
        goto promote;
    }
    else
    {
        if (workinput == "Work")
        {
            money += jobmoney;
            goto work;
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    goto start;
succb:
    system("CLS");
    cout << "You successfully bought this item!" << endl;
    cout << "Your balance:" <<money << endl;
    cout << "Type in back to continue!" << endl;
    bck = "non";
    cin >> bck;
    if (bck == "back")
    {
        goto start;
    }
    goto start;
promote:
    system("CLS");
    cout << string( 20, '/n' );
    cout << "Type in JobInfo for more information!" << endl;
    cout << "Type in OK to try to get a promotion!" << endl;
//continue this
    cin.get();
    goto start;
stat:
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Your stats:" << endl;
    cout << "SNK "<<snk << endl;
    cout << "SHRT "<<shirt << endl;
    cout << "JOB "<<job << endl;
    cout << "MONEY "<<money << endl;
    cout << "JOBMONEY "<<jobmoney << endl;
    bck = "null";
    cin >> bck;
    if (bck == "back")
    {
        goto start;
    }
    goto stat;
chlog:
    system("CLS");
    cout << "CHLOGTARTALOM" << endl;
    cout << "Type in back for main menu!" << endl;
    bck = "null";
    cin >> bck;
    if (bck == "back")
    {
        goto start;
    }
    goto chlog;
admin:
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Admin panel:" << endl;
    cout << "Type in your password!" << endl;
    cin >> admininput;
    if (admininput == "hmalphabranch")
    {
        goto adminpanel;
    }
    else
    {
        goto start;
    }
adminpanel:
    system("CLS");
    cout << "You can't do nothing here" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `goto`.  There may be times when it is needed but this is not it.  simple loops and functions will do what you need.

Comment: Once you get that error solved, I hope you don't want us to debug it with all of those `goto` calls.  See [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Comment: "3 cppfiles" versus "the other file". Is it 3 or 2? And why do you have the same code in two different cpp files?

Comment: dont use `goto`, dont use `using namespace std;`, seperate in/output from logic, break your code down to smaller functions, after all make use of c++: define custom structs where appropriate instead of using lots of dependant variables with cryptic names

Comment: You're linking multiple files with enstart() defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple definitions of a function named `enstart`, you can fix that by

- using different names, or
- putting them in differently named namespaces.

By the way, `'/n'` doesn't denote a newline character. It's a multi-byte character constant, with implementation-defined value. Write `'\n'` where you want a newline character.

---

In other news:

- A `goto` to a label earlier in the code, usually corresponds to a *loop*. Look up the `for`, `while` and `do` loops.
- A `goto` to a block of code that ends with a `goto` back, usually corresponds to a call of a function. You already know how to define simple functions. Just use them instead of labeled blocks of code.
- Free tools such as AStyle can help you format your code with proper indentation, automatically. Many editors can also do this. I used AStyle to format your code in the question.